# How to Apply multiple map layers on map using openlayers through checkbox?

Tags: javascript, laravel, openlayers

I wnat to show multiple layers on map thar has a baselayer showinn using openlayers when i click a check box. for example if i click a checkbox name Population and another checkbox name Income and sale the can show specific layer that i applied on my backend APi.

I have tried this by using jquery . First i put the`enter code here` values of checkbox in a variable the i pass a change function for to checkboxes the code is below. the i pass the variable to the map object . but the map does not work it throws an error that Ol_uid not found.

```
var check = document.querySelectorAll('#main-side > ul > li > ul > li input[type=checkbox]')
$(check).change(function () {

                let checked = this.checked;
                var test = new ol.layer.Image({
                    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                        url: 'http://3.16.123.168:8080/geoserver/wms?',
                        params: {
                            'LAYERS': `twmp:${$(this).val()} `
                        },
                        ratio: 1,
                        serverType: 'geoserver',
                        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
                    })
                });
                test.setVisible(checked);

                console.log(test);
            });
<code>
var map = new ol.Map({
                layers: [
                    new ol.layer.VectorTile({
                        declutter: true,
                        source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
                            attributions: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> ' +
                                '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">' +
                                'OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
                            format: new ol.format.MVT(),
                            url: 'https://{a-d}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6/' +
                                '{z}/{x}/{y}.vector.pbf?access_token=' + key
                        }),
                        style: createMapboxStreetsV6Style(ol.style.Style, ol.style.Fill, ol
                            .style.Stroke, ol
                            .style.Icon, ol.style.Text)
                    }),
                    test
                ],
                target: 'map',
                view: view
            });
```

I expect to pass the value of checkbox to the variable

Comment: `test` isn't defined until you click the checkbox so you need `map.addLayer(test)` in the function instead of including `test` in the map constructor.  An alternative would be to create an initial test layer at startup and use `test.getSouce().updateParams({'LAYERS': `twmp:${$(this).val()} `});` in your change function to update the WMS layer instead of creating separate OpenLayers layers for each WMS layer.

Comment: There is one more thing if i console log test outside of function it shows undfined so how can that be solved if there is no value in test

Comment: You can make it global: define `var test;` before the function and assign it in the function `test = new ol.layer.Image({` without var.

Comment: It works fine for adding a layer but when i uncheck the check box it does not remove the layer. i even tried with map.removeLayer(test) it does not remove the layer after the i applied if else condition but that does not work to.if (checked === true) {
                    test.setVisible(checked);
                    map.addLayer(test);
                }
                else{
                    test.setVisible(checked);
                    map.removeLayer(test);
                }

Comment: Thank you mike for time and helping me out